# Purchasing a car from a private seller in CA as a PA resident

Tags: united-states, car, california, pennsylvania

I'm currently a resident of Pennsylvania, and I'm planning to purchase a second-hand car from a private seller in California. To my knowledge, vehicle purchase is a two-step process:

1. Transfer the title from the seller to the buyer; and
2. Register the vehicle under the new owner in the state DMV (For PA, this involves filing a MV-1 with a DMV agent).

I'm a bit confused about the first step:

It initially seemed to me there are two ways, either first have the seller transfer the title into PA and then file for a ownership change with PA DMV, or first file for a title change in CA and then transfer the title into PA myself.

However, based on my research, transferring an out-of-state title into PA requires the owner of the car to be a PA resident (but my seller clearly isn't), so it seems like the only way is to change the vehicle's title in CA upon purchase, then transfer the title into PA myself. Is my interpretation accurate?

Finally, I expect that after the completion of step 1, I'll have to move the car into PA and then finish step 2 by filing an MV-1 form with a local DMV agent. I'm wondering if I can first complete the title transfer, move the car into PA (using a 3rd-party moving company), and then complete the registration after the move? I understand that in this case, I'll be unable to drive the car before I could register it, but in my situation this might actually be easier.

PS: There are no lienholders involved in this transaction; the vehicle is wholly owned by the seller.

Comment: Don't know about Pennsylvania in particular, but having done it with other states, generally you just need the signed title.  You may have to bring the car to your DMV for an inspection - VIN number check at a minimum, maybe safety/smog if your state requires it.  But you should be aware that, unless the car is something fairly unusual (exotics, classics, and so on), there's a good chance that it could be a scam - especially if it's a real bargain, owned by military person posted overseas, &c.  More detail would help.

Comment: [This section](https://www.dmv.pa.gov/VEHICLE-SERVICES/Title-Registration/Pages/Buying-a-Vehicle.aspx#out) from PennDOT about buying a used vehicle with an out-of-state title doesn't seem to say it's a two-step process. Where did you read about it?